# Index and match approximate in row and column formula not working

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

I have a table. In column "A" there are heights, and in row "2" there are widths. The initial input for width and height are given by the user. And the output should be a given length.

The code I have is
=INDEX(B3:Z16;MATCH(H20;B2:Z2;1);MATCH(H21;A3:A16;1))

For some reason the formula outputs a seemingly random cell in the table.

What I try to do is to let the user input dimensions and then if needed approximate the 1st lower value to give the corresponding length.

What am I doing wrong?

Table used:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTVo8.png)

Comment: I suggest to post a data example. Your input and expected output may be useful

Comment: B3:Z16 (index) & B2:B16 (match) range has overlap.. try to correct that and share us the outcome.. ( :

Comment: Corrected the formula but still get a wrong value. I added the table in my post. If I for example give an input of width 150 and height 287. It gives me the output 709 instead of 808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
=INDEX(B3:Z16;MATCH(H21;A3:A16;-1);MATCH(H20;B2:Z2;1))
```

Comment: I tried and corrected my formula but still get a wrong value. For example I give an input of width 150 and height 287. It gives me the output 709 instead of 808.

Comment: The column A sorting order in your table is Descending, that made a confusion and besides, the rows and columns were switched. I've edited the answer, can you try now?

Comment: I reversed the sorting order and added your code. It seems to work smoothly now. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that so mark my answer as accepted please.